# How to get the music player status in Android?

Tags: android, status, audio-player, android-music-player

Can anyone tell me how to get the status of the music player in Android? I want know whether the music player is paused or playing. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
boolean isPlaying = player.isPlaying();
```

:)

Comment: can i access the same piece of code from another app say like Clock. Actually am using Mediaplayer interface in the another app.....    Thanks for your info...

Comment: You should be able to access a MediaPlayer you define within your app using normal Java context rules.  Please make sure you mark an answer as correct if it answers your question.

Comment: You probably don't want to store player.isPlaying anywhere though, since it won't be updated when the player begins to play.

Comment: This is true (unless you store it as a reference).  I just wanted to be explicit about what it was returning :D